# SharePoint Hosted App show profile picture of the logged in user

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created SharePoint Hosted App. I am loading current user profile data from user profile service. When loading the image using PictureURL property image loading fail.

1. Tried directly using the PictureURL which points to mysite user photos location.
2. Tried using host web layouts userphoto.aspx url.

But both scenarios failed to load the profile picture. I have understood this issue is because of cross domain url.

Please help how to solve this problem.

-Praveen.

Comment: Option 2: Don't use the HostWeb url, but AppWeb. http://www.sharepointappie.nl/office-365-profile-pictures-showing/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using AppWeb only. it's SharePoint hosted app in office 365. I have tried all the ways, but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. My experience was even if you have `CrossDomainPhotosEnabled` set to `TRUE`, then also option 1 (PictureURL from MySite) won't work unless you access that URL once in your browser.

I found option 2 better as cross domain call to host web is allowed by default. Though, option 2 takes some time to reflect.

Check [this link](https://mysharepointlearnings.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/user-profile-picture-in-sp-hosted-app/) for more detailed information

Comment: So, there is no other way to get the profile picture then. I am not sure why the host web url is not allowed in hosted apps.

Comment: It is allowed. Please go through the attached link once. You can show profile pic in app

Comment: Garima, I have clearly explained scenario 2 in my post. I have tried using the host web url to layouts userphoto.aspx. But, the images are not loading. It gives me cross mark. But the same works fine in App Part. IF I type the url directly then the url redirection happening to login.microsoftonline.com which means it still looking for authentication. I am using IE 11 and Chrome.

Comment: Could you share the userphoto.aspx url with me? I am using the same in my SP hosted app and it is working.

Comment: See mine here. https://companyname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname=i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cuseralias%40companyname.com

Comment: Use accountname=company@sharepoint.com. Basically accountname query string parameter refers to email id of user and not 'accountname' property in user profile.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint team has added a new feature to SharePoint that allows us to show profile pictures cross-domain.

It’s a very simple operation and just requires some basic PowerShell skills. Basically all you need to do is to set the `CrossDomainPhotosEnabled` property on the `SPWebApplication` object to true, like this:

```
asnp Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://intranet.contoso.com
$wa.CrossDomainPhotosEnabled = $true
$wa.Update()
```

After that you can render MySite profile picture by following steps given in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112933/display-a-current-user-profile-picture) article.

For more information on Powershell for Windows Online, [click here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161397(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: It is not on On-premise. Anyway I have tried this very first when I was facing this issue. It didn't solve my problem.